# SQL get sum of one column and sum of different column with where in one query?

Tags: mysql

This is my table

```
| value  | count | type |
|   5    |  2    | Bike |
|   5    |  2    | Bike |
|   5    |  1    | Car  |
|   2    |  3    | Car  |
```

I'm trying to get the sum of the count column where value = 5.

Then in the same query get the sum of the count column where value = 5 and type = Bike.

So the result should be:

5 for the first sum

4 for the second sum

Is this possible in one query?

Comment: Please post the expected result. Also, please specify the correct dbms. Is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one query using conditional aggregation.

```
select 
 sum(case when value=5 then count else 0 end) as sum_1
,sum(case when value=5 and type='Bike' then count else 0 end) as sum_2
from yourtable
```

Answer (score -2):

for mysql

```
    select sum(count) from table where value = 5;

select sum(count) from table where value = 5 and Type like 'bike';
```

Comment: that is multiple queries